# How to bind an event to content loaded asynchronously?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my html:

```
<div class="mydiv" data-cid="1">
    <div class="mydiv2">
        <p>
            <b>Call this text...</b> 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am binding this event handler:

```
$(".mydiv").on('longtap',function(e,data)
{
    cid = this.getAttribute('data-cid');
    message = $(this).html(); // I want only B-Tag like this.b...
    if(this.getAttribute('data-cid')) doit(......); 
});
```

My problem is that if I load later with AJAX, the long-click method does not work anymore

My AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php?file=chat&readline=1', 
    success: function(data)
    {
        $("#content").append(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. your first div is not closed 2. there is no jquery event handler called 'longtap' (although jquery mobile has 'taphold') 3. the data-id is not in the same div as the one you are referencing in your jquery

Comment: I'm with Rachel - I'm quite perplexed as to how this works at all given all the errors in the code you've posted. I'm glad my answer was helpful, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that you are binding an event handler to an element that does not yet exist on the page. The easiest way to handle a case like this is to use event delegation, which lets you bind to a parent element like the document that *is* on the page when the event is bound:

```
$(document).on('longtap', '.mydiv', function(e, data)
{
    cid = this.getAttribute('data-cid');
    message = $(this).html(); // I want only B-Tag like this.b...
    if(this.getAttribute('data-cid')) doit(......); 
});
```

This works because the event handler is bound to the document, which is of course always present, but the handler will only actually trigger if the event triggers on an element that matches the delegation selector (".mydiv" in this case).

Comment: Thank you, i understand now and the ajax works fine now!

Comment: Sorry, jetzt habe ich gesehen das du Deutscher bist :) Danke nochmal, jetzt muss ich nur noch das erste Problem hin bekommen und dann ist alles ok

Comment: Please please please do not bind to the document.  This can seriously hinder the performance of a website.  Use a container.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `mydiv2` is **inside** `.mydiv`, you can solve both problems like this:

```js
$(document).on('longtap', '.mydiv', function(e, data) {
    cid = this.getAttribute('data-cid');
    message = $(this).html('<b>' + $(this).find('b').html() + '</b>');
    if (this.getAttribute('data-cid')) doit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv" data-cid="1">
    <div class="mydiv2">
        <p>
            <b>Call this text...</b> 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This binds the `longtap` event to the document, so you can load more content via Ajax and the event will still be triggered properly.

Besides, this finds `<b>` to show just it, as you expected.

Comment: I ended up answering the "original" question where you mentioned the two problems I solved above. I just noted the question was edited after posting my answer. I hope it helps, anyway :)

Comment: is comes [object Object] :)

Comment: You're right. I just edited the answer with a little adjustment for solving that ;)